# how to setup access retraction for DB-user in HANA database

Tags: hana

I got a request from business end user about retraction in production system.

We have one user which need access to production system but business team agree to provide only two day a week and just 2hour window only.

User access day and timings:

- Wednesday : 3pm PT to 4pmPT .
- Saturday : 2 to 4 pm PT.

I am not sure how can we restrict user like this.

Please let me know if you know any ideas

Answer (score 0):

You could create a stored procedure to activate / deactivate said user. The procedures could be defined with definer privileges. Then you create a "BATCH" user with execute privileges for those two procedures.
Finally you can setup a cron job to call the procedures with the help of "hdbsql".

Of course you could use cron + hdbsql directly but this would imply that the cron user would have significantly elevated privileges. This in turn might cause a large security issue.